# Acess to Local and VPN Network while staying connectet to the Internet

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, internet, local

i would like a VPN connection with the Windows VPN client in the latest Windows 10 Build. While i'm connected i would like to have access to the VPN computers (see them on the Network to share Files and stuff) and also would like to access the internet, but due to the fact i don't have acces to the internet through the VPN i would like to use my local connection, and also would like to use my Homenetwork in the same way as the VPN ( file share etc.)

THE VPN is no Company VPN but i can't change settings but i may ask if things are changed.

So my Problem is:
I am connectet to the VPN.
I am don't have access to the internet.
I can ping the Computer in the VPN network.

When I disable the Standart Gateway in the IP V4/6 settings for the VPN I have access to the internet, BUT i can no longer ping the computer on the VPN network.

And i would like to combine this so i can:

connect to the VPN
connect to the Internet 
ping and access the Computer on the VPN network
ping and access my local NAS

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly.

You need to disable the gateway setting, so not all traffic goes over the VPN connection.

You figured out you can't ping devices in this method. The reason is likely because you are pinging based on DNS rather than to IP address. DNS does not work correctly with VPN, but once you know the ip address and use that directly, you can work with it as you want, because the ip address knows by range to which network it is supposed to look and will correctly find the route to the device over VPN vs the device in your local network.

Comment: okay seems logic so far, but I'm also trying to use the VPN for me and my Friends for  "Local" Multiplayer games like Warcraft III, Anno 1404 etc. And those games won't go over the VPN when I Disable the Gateway. Is there any way I can do the "local" Multiplayer and have access to the Internet?

Comment: Due to the nature of how games communicate with players, it really depends on the game, but most likely not going to work.

Comment: okay then no internet for me while warcraft III